# How to add entity in WordPress that have metadata such as name, age

Tags: plugins, front-end

I work on CMS for Education academy and we need to add data about students in small horizontal cards. I need to know how to create entity has one to many relationship and pass it to the frontend. And is it possible in WordPress.com or in org.

Comment: It all depends. WordPress has  `*_meta` fields available; you can add metadata to posts or to users. You'd probably be looking for a plugin, or writing one yourself; WordPress.com has limited plugins available, as I understand it, and I doubt you'd be able to upload your own code. (Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.) If you're running self-hosted (ie, ".org") you can add any plugins you'd like.

Comment: can you please recommend a powerful plugin based on your experience.

Comment: Not really, because generally I've just written what I need. I've used [CMB2](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2) extensively as a handy library; others on this site use [ACF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) a lot, but I've got 0 experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

A high level answer is take a look at post meta: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/assign-custom-fields/ Custom meta fields can be added and retrieved for any post/page and displayed on the front end.

Also see https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ which runs on either wordpress.org or .com versions.